# using delay in tab control before the data is insert into textbox in wpf

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I am new in wpf. I am using the tabcontrol. and there are two tabs. I want that on change the tab all the contents of tab load. and then I am inserting some text in a text box. I want delay of 5 sec before text is insert in textbox. I illustrate this with images.
below is the open tabcontrol.

[image]

When I click on connect its display the following.

[image]

on right side there is a textbox with text "vokkey, Dave". I want that after the tab load it's wait for 5 second and then the text "vokkey,dave" appear in textbox. on which event should i work.? and for delay what should i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is customary to use a `DispatcherTimer` for these situations... put this into your `UserControl`:

In the constructor:

```
Loaded += YourControl_Loaded;
```

Then in the code behind of the `UserControl`:

```
private void YourControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
    timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5);
    timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;
    timer.Start();
}

...

private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox.Text = "vokkey, Dave";
    timer.Stop();
}
```

You can find out more about the `DispatcherTimer` from the [DispatcherTimer Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer.aspx) page at MSDN.